# What is the difference between the closure of a set and a closed set?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, terminology

Is "closure" and "closed" interchangeable? Can a set be a closure of a set without being closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure of a set $S$, $\rm{cl}(S)$, can be defined as the intersection of all closed sets containing $S$ -- that is, $\rm{cl}(S) = \bigcap \{C \mid C \text{ closed}, S \subseteq C\}$.

This is a closed set, so no a set cannot be the closure of a set without being closed.

The terms are in a sense interchangeable, as given a closed set $C$, it is the case that $\rm{cl}(C) = C$, so every closed set is the closure of some set -- itself.

Comment: Just to clarify, suppose I had an open disk, then the closure of that disk is the boundary of the disk plus the disk, and that is the closed disk.

Comment: @FemaleTank That's correct. Every set $A$ has a smallest closed set which contains $A$.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not interchangeable. A closed set has the property of being closed. The closure of a set $A$ is always closed, but the set $A$ needs not have to property of being closed.

Closedness is a property and the closure is actually a function that maps a set onto a closed set.

Comment: Not true that $A$ must not be closed.   The point here is that $A$ MIGHT not be closed.

Comment: Sorry, translation mistake from german… You are right.

Answer (score 0):

In topology, closed sets are exactly the same as the closures of (not necessarily closed) sets. The closure of a set is closed because it is the intersection of a collection of closed sets, and a closed set is the closure of itself.

Answer (score 0):

The closure of a set $M$ equals $M$ iff $M$ is closed.

Comment: The point is that cl(M) =M can be used to identify a closed set.