# closed set vs. its closure

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to understand the concept of closure, and read the [Closure (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(mathematics)) section of Wikipedia, which says:

> When a set S is not closed under some operations, one can usually find the smallest set containing S that is closed. This smallest closed set is called the closure of S (with respect to these operations). For example, the closure under subtraction of the set of natural numbers, viewed as a subset of the real numbers, is the set of integers.

I also read [Math Stack Exchange link re: this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393701/what-is-the-difference-between-the-closure-of-a-set-and-a-closed-set) but it did not clarify my question, which is: Is the closure a smaller set than our original or a larger set that meets the criteria? I did review the other questions but they are all more advanced. My question is just clarification of the definition.

My interpretation from the above comment is that the closure of a set is larger than itself ( from looking at the part that says: ...smallest set containing S...I just want to make sure I am reading this right and understand what it is trying to say. Basically because the result of the operation is not in the set of natural numbers, we can see if there is a larger set that contains the answer and the original set. Is that right? Or is it that the closure of a set is a subset of it that meets our requirement ( i.e. if we take two numbers from that smaller set and subtract them, the answer would always be in the same set ) I seem to get both definitions depending on where I look for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second link deals with any one notion of closure, topological closure, but as your first indicates, the concept is much more general. It arises whenever you have a set $X$ and some operation defined on $X$: then for any $S\subseteq X$ you can ask whether applying the operation to members of $S$ always produces a result in $S$. If the answer is *yes*, we say that the set $S$ is *closed under the operation*.

> For example, take $X$ to be the set $\Bbb R$ of real numbers. The subset $\Bbb Z^+$ consisting of the positive integers is closed under the operation of addition, because the sum of two positive integers is always a positive integer. It is not closed under the operation of subtraction, however, because, for instance, $1-2$ is not a positive integer, even though $1$ and $2$ are positive integers. The subset $\Bbb Z$ of $X$ consisting of all integers, however, is closed under subtraction: the difference of any two integers is an integer.
>
> In a topological setting the operation of interest is that of taking limit points of a set: a set $S$ in a topological space $X$ is closed under taking limits if it contains all of its limit points, and in this context we simply say that it is closed. This is the notion of closure dealt with in your second link.
>
> Your first link has a number of other examples, though many of them depend on some knowledge of more advanced concepts.

Given some $S\subseteq X$ that is not closed under the operation, we are often interested in expanding $S$ to a set that **is** closed under the operation. More specifically, though, we want to do this by adding as little as possible to $S$.

> In my first example above, for instance, I could expand $\Bbb Z^+$ to $\Bbb Q$, the set of rational numbers, or even to $\Bbb R$ itself, to get a set that (a) contains $\Bbb Z^+$ and (b) is closed under subtraction, but each throws in far more than is necessary: $\Bbb Z$, on the other hand, contains only those real numbers that we absolutely have to add to $\Bbb Z^+$ to get a set closed under subtraction.

There are two fundamentally different ways to try to do this. One is to begin by adding to $S$ all the of the missing results of applying the operation to members of $S$; this is essentially what we do to get $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb Z^+$ when we try to close the latter under subtraction. Sometimes, however, the resulting set **isn’t** closed under the operation, because applying it to some of the newly added members produces results that aren’t in the extended set. Then we have to repeat the procedure, tossing these new results into the set as well. It may even be necessary to do this infinitely many times.

The other approach is to do it all at once by taking the intersection of all subsets $C$ of $X$ such that (a) $S\subseteq C$, and (b) $C$ is closed under the operation. Call this intersection $\overline S$. It is not hard to see that $S\subseteq\overline S$ and that $\overline S$ is closed under the operation. Since $\overline S$ is a subset of **every** subset of $X$ that contains $S$ and is closed under the operation, it is clearly the minimal expansion of $S$ to a set closed under the operation: everything in $\overline S$ has to be there if we’re to have a set that contains $S$ and is closed under the operation.

Either approach, however, makes it clear that the closure of $S$ under an operation always contains $S$ as a subset; that’s really part of the definition. And it is equal to $S$ precisely when $S$ is already closed under the operation.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to provide such an amazing answer.

Comment: @Saaman: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of closedness as a topological property of sets. Closure, on the other hand, is an operation that can be applied to a set $S$ in order to get the smallest(in the sense of set inclusion) closed set of $S$.

To answer your question, if your set is closed, then the closure of it is just the original set. However, if you find the closure of an open set, you will end up with a closed set that contains your set (which is larger, again, in the sense of set inclusion).

Finally, whether a set is open or closed depend on the topology on the space you choose the set from. Without further information about what space(e.g. natural number, rational, real, etc. ) you are looking at, I hope this answer is still helpful to you somehow.

Comment: yes; thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a topological space. We say that a subset $C$ of $X$ is *closed* if its complement $X\setminus C$ is open. If $A$ is any subset of $X$, then the *closure* of $A$ is defined as the smallest closed subset of $X$ that contains $A$. We denote the closure of $A$ by $\overline{A}$. You can check that an arbitrary union of closed sets is again closed. Hence
$$\overline{A}=\bigcap_{\substack{A\subset C\subset X\\ C \ \text{is closed}}}C.$$